# Insert a building block in a table in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

with a button in the form, I want to insert a row on the second table of my document that I have already define as a building block (quickparts) So the building block IS a row of table. I need to insert it in the place of the 2nd row. Obviously, I don't get it...
Important to note that I already have controls in that building block (Datepicker, Listbox, checkbox and button)

Here's what I wrote

```vb
Private Sub btn_Valider_Click()

    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim Ins As Range

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set Ins = Row(2)

    Table.buildingblockinsert(Ins, Proposition, Quick Parts, general, Building Blocks.dotx)

End Sub
```

I tried to follow the syntax from the microsoft but being slightly autistic, some obvious detail for experience programmer may not come to my mind... I can't reproduce what they explain...

Comment: See code for insertion of building blocks on my page: https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock. It is not straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you have to split the table to insert a row. This example uses the Selection object to insert a row from AutoText at a spot where you've clicked:

```
Sub AddTableRow()
    With Selection
        .MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        .SplitTable
        ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries("QuoteTableRow").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
        .Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    End With
End Sub
```

You can also define a Range to do something similar without having to select anything, but it means the target document must always be set up the same way so that Word can find the table reliably.

Comment: Provided the building block includes the end of row marker it can be inserted without splitting the table. The insertion range needs to be the first cell of the row that will be after the inserted row.